# Remove redundant items from a list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts based on user selections from a GUI (Plotly returns.) When a user clicks a data point (or group of data points), the datapoint(s) is added to the list.

However, if the user clicks the same data point (or selects a group of datapoints, which includes a datapoint already selected) **then redundant dictionaries appear in the list for the redundant data point(s)**.

I.e.

```
[
  {  
    "clicked": true,
    "selected": true,
    "hovered": false,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 71100.0988957607,
    "selected_xcol": "injection_id",
    "xvalue": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f",
    "selected_ycol": "peak_area",
    "yvalue": 71100.0988957607,
    "injection_id": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f"
  },
  {
    "clicked": true,
    "selected": true,
    "hovered": false,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 75283.2386064552,
    "selected_xcol": "injection_id",
    "xvalue": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f",
    "selected_ycol": "peak_area",
    "yvalue": 75283.2386064552,
    "injection_id": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f"
  },
  {  # Redundant, same as first item
    "clicked": true,
    "selected": true,
    "hovered": false,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 71100.0988957607,
    "selected_xcol": "injection_id",
    "xvalue": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f",
    "selected_ycol": "peak_area",
    "yvalue": 71100.0988957607,
    "injection_id": "e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f"
  }
]
```

Because users can select one or multiple datapoints in one GUI stroke, and the code doesn't know which, I simply add the returned list to the cumulative list like so...

```
LOCAL["selected_data"] += selectable_data_chart(LOCAL["df"], 
                                               key = "st_react_plotly_control_main_chart",
                                               custom_data_columns = custom_data_columns, 
                                               hovertemplate = hovertemplate, 
                                               svgfilename = svgfilename)
```

I have tried filtering out the redundant items with ...

```
LOCAL["selected_data"] = list(set(LOCAL["selected_data"]))
```

...but it raises an error...

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I have also tried...

```
result = []
LOCAL["selected_data"] = [result.append(d) for d in LOCAL["selected_data"] if d not in result]
```

...but it returns null no matter what.

```
[
  null,
  null
]
```

Comment: It looks like the dictionaries you want to merge have different values for some keys. Can you define when two dictionaries should be considered duplicates?

Comment: Sorry. Typo.   ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a mutable value to a set (or use it as a dictionary key)...what if, after adding an item to a set, you changed the values so that it was identical to another set member? That would invalidate the guarantees provided by the `set` data type.

One possible solution is to transform your dictionaries into a structured type. For example, using the `dataclasses` module, we could write (assuming that your sample data is contained in the file `data.json`):

```
import json
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Event:
    clicked: bool
    selected: bool
    hovered: bool
    x: float
    y: float
    selected_xcol: str
    xvalue: float
    selected_ycol: str
    yvalue: float
    injection_id: str


with open("data.json") as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)

events = set(Event(**item) for item in data)
```

As @lemon pointed out in a comment, this won't actually work for the sample data in your question, because the third item in the list is **not** identical to the first item (in the first item, `x=0`, but in the third item, `x="e54112f9-4497-4a7e-91cd-e26842a4092f"`). If this was just a typo when entering your question, the solution here will work just fine.

---

A less structured solution would be to transform each dictionary into a list of tuples using the `items()` method, turn that into a `tuple`, and then add those to your "unique" set:

```
import json

with open("data.json") as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)

events = set(tuple(item.items()) for item in data)
```

In this case, `events` is a set of tuples; you could transform it back into a list of dictionaries like this:

```
dict_events = [dict(item) for item in events]
```